# Base layout for tiles

Tags: java, tiles

What if I did not put layout properties and try to use them. Like in the example below I did not define body `<put-attribute name="body" value="" />` in `baseLayout` but I use it in `<definition name="login"` Is this necessary to define 'body' in baaselayout if it is used in any other definition?

```
<definition name="baseLayout" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/layout.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="" />
    <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/header.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="navigation" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/navigation.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/footer.jsp" />
</definition>

<definition name="login" extends="baseLayout">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Login" />
    <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/loginHeader.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/footer.jsp" />
</definition>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case its not. Using the "template" attribute you are always creating a new layout. Have a look a the "extends" attribute for cascading layout definitions.